# If an electron decays to the ground state, are there any limits on the possible decay routes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons, radiation

Let's say that an electron is in the $|4 1 1 \rangle$ state of the hydrogen atom and it decays to the ground state. I think that it's easy to list all of the possible decay routes by just using the rules for the quantum numbers: $l=0...n-1$ and $m=-l ...+l$. But are there are decay routes that might be excluded for any reason?

Comment: You mean, apart from the usual selection rules?

Comment: Are you admitting all possible mechanisms, for example, by collision?   (Small pedantic point of semantics:  the *electron* does not decay, the *atom* decays.)

Comment: @garyp electric dipole transitions only

Comment: @EmilioPisanty sure?